# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string python pymysql (Delete row)

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

This is my code...

```
    sql = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s < NOW() - INTERVAL %s YEAR"
    delete_list = [{'TABLE_NM': 'tb_user', 'COLUMN_NM': 'CRTE_DT', 'YEAR': 3}]
    cursor.executemany(sql, delete_list)
    connection.commit()
```

> > python run~

Error code :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~PATH", line 30, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(sql, (delete_list['TABLE_NM'], delete_list['COLUMN_NM'], delete_list['YEAR']))
  File "~PATH\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 182, in executemany
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "~PATH"\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 182, in <genexpr>
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "~PATH\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 146, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "~PATH\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 125, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Can anyone help this error...?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewong Include the full traceback error~ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE CRTE_DT < NOW() - INTERVAL %s YEAR"
delete_list = [3]
cursor.executemany(sql, delete_list)
connection.commit()
```

column and table should rarely be variable.

Comment: Is it impossible to be variable?

Comment: Column and table can never be as parameter. Only values